# how to display HTML content in RenderTable column

Tags: c#, html, pdf

I am working on a project where I need to display a PDF and some contents on it.

I am using `PdfExporter` to generate the PDF and RenderTable to display different contents.

Now I want to display some HTML content on pdf

I am doing it like this

```
RenderTable table = new RenderTable();
var titleRow = table.Rows[0];
titleRow[0].Text = "<b>Hello</b>";
doc.Body.Children.Add(table); //here doc is C1PrintDocument
```

This is not working .
The text on pdf displays as `<b>Hello</b>` but I want it as **Hello**

any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
output$example <- renderTable({
   table <- someTable_Data_here
   table
}, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

Comment: Please explaing the code intead of posting only code